# Syntax is not a function 

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Here is my SQL statement:

```
 N.File_Id = ServerFiles.Id WHERE [...]
```

'File_Id' is highlighted in pink, is there anyway I can override this? I think this is why my SQL is not returning a result set.

Thanks

Amended code:

```
SELECT 
   N.Id, NLoc.N_Id, Loc.Id as Loc_Id, 
   CAST(N.Text AS TEXT) as Text, FilePath, 
   CAST(N.Title AS TEXT) as Title, N.CreatD as RegDate
FROM 
   NLoc 
JOIN N ON NLoc.Not_Id = N.Id 
JOIN Loc ON NLoc.Loc_Id = Loc.Id
JOIN ServerFiles ON N.File_Id = ServerFiles.Id 
WHERE 
    Loc_Id IN (1)
```

Comment: Can you post the entire SQL?  It's difficult to tell what you're trying to do here.

Comment: Please add a bit more information like your complete SQL statement, what you're trying to achieve, what you've already tried, ...

Comment: Is that your full SQL? If so you're missing Select and From parts. If not make sure you define your alias (N) in the from statement.

Comment: ouch for the negative reps. Ok will amend it. Sorry.

Comment: I'm noticing you use N.File_Id and N.Id, are you sure you have both of those columns in your table? Can you post your schema?

Comment: **File_Id** is hi-lited in pink because there is a system function called File_Id. Enclose it in brackets N.[File_Id].

This is probably not related to your problem of the query not returning a dataset.

Comment: I had to use a FULL OUTER JOIN as well as [ ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    N.Id
    , NLoc.N_Id
    , Loc.Id as Loc_Id
    , CAST(N.Text AS TEXT) as Text
    , FilePath
    , CAST(N.Title AS TEXT) as Title
    , N.CreatD as RegDate 

FROM NLoc 
     JOIN N  ON NLoc.Not_Id=N.Id 
     JOIN Loc ON NLoc.Loc_Id=Loc.Id 
     JOIN ServerFiles ON N.File_Id=ServerFiles.Id 
WHERE Loc.Id = 1
```

The first problem I see is that you can't use alias defined in your SELECT inside WHERE statement (so you can't use Loc_Id you must go with Loc.Id).

Let me know if this works for you or you still get an error.

I'm also noticing you use N.File_Id and N.Id, are you sure you have both of those columns in your table? Can you post your schema?

Comment: Whether it will be NLoc.Loc_Id or Loc.Id  is again a question?

Comment: @NiladriBiswas Since he's joining on those column both will have the same value so it doesn't matter which one of those two he uses.

Comment: Yes ..you r right... Something wrong is happening with me ..should move out of the comp. screen now... need seriously break.

Answer (score 0):

Place it in **[ ]** like **[N].[File_Id]**

```
SELECT 
N.Id, NLoc.N_Id, 
Loc.Id as Loc_Id, CAST(N.Text AS TEXT) as Text, 
FilePath, CAST(N.Title AS TEXT) as Title,
 N.CreatD as RegDate 

 FROM NLoc 
 JOIN N  ON NLoc.Not_Id=N.Id 
 JOIN Loc ON NLoc.Loc_Id=Loc.Id 
 JOIN ServerFiles ON [N].[File_Id]=ServerFiles.Id 
 WHERE NLoc.Loc_Id IN (1) -- or Loc.Id IN (1)
```

Comment: Your code as well as comment have errors. You can't use table name and the column inside the same brackets, it'd have to be [N].[File_Id], but there's no need for that. Also you can't use Loc_Id inside the where statement.

Comment: Sorry for the bracket mistake. I have updated.